# Extract a list or catalogue from a column containing JSON values in Postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a data table `my_table` that looks like the following

```
| id | column1 | data       |
|----+---------+------------|
| 1  | value_1 | ["A", "B"] |
| 2  | value_2 | ["B", "C"] |
| 3  | value_3 | ["A", "C"] |
| 4  | value_4 | ["E", "B"] |
```

I would need to extract a list of all the unique json strings in the column `data`, such as

```
"A"
"B"
"C"
"D"
"E"
```

I tried some json functions found in the Postgresql documentation like:

```
select * from json_each_text(select data from my_table as foo)
```

but I am getting syntax error at or near "from" (the second 'from').

I also tried taking out the alias outside the parenthesis to affect the first 'select'. Nothing has been successful so far.

I can access the information contained in the column and extract individual values or counts when I do:

```
select count(*) from my_table
  where data::jsonb ? 'A' = true;
```

The result is '2', which is the expected.

How can I get a list of the values contained in the json column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [`json_array_elements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) (or [`jsonb_array_elements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) if datatype is jsonb ) to turn a json(b) array into rows :

```
select distinct t.value::text
from my_table
cross join json_array_elements(data) t
```

Which for this simple data :

```
create table my_table (
  id int,
  column1 varchar(20),
  data json
);

insert into my_table values
(1,  'value_1',  '["A", "B"]'),
(2,  'value_2',  '["B", "C"]'),
(3,  'value_3',  '["A", "C"]'),
(4,  'value_4',  '["E", "B"]');
```

Results :

```
value
"A"
"C"
"B"
"E"
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/I6FAIC8E)

Comment: I only have to add that the function that worked for me is `jsonb_array_elements()` since the one proposed is a non exisisting one according to the error messages. Other than that, the code works really well!

Comment: `cross join lateral` is more explicit than using a `,`